# zookeeper: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, unsupported-class-version

I'm trying to follow the guide on the kafka website:
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
But when I use kafka_2.12-2.5.0 and try to start the zookeeper I get:

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  config/zookeeper.properties
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeerMain : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I'm using redhat7.1.
Tried to update java:

```
$ sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
...
Package 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.31-2.b13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What version of Java should I have?

Answer (score 1):

This '52.0' means that it's compiled with 1.8 jdk, but you are triying to run mainly with lower one (or even very high incompatible?).
By default use the JAVA_HOME environment variable, so hope you already checked the basics: java_home, java --version... or even force an export of java_home just before running pointing a proper 32/64 java

Comment: I see that the java version is "1.7.0_75", but I did yum install the 1.8... How can I force it to use 1.8?

Comment: First confirm that you have actually installed jdk 1.8 and in which path is it (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk -... ??)
Also check your /home/username/.bashrc to see if there is an default export JAVA_HOME = "/ path / to / oldjava7 / home"

Then consider overwriting that path so 1.8 will be the default for now on for everyone
OR for just the your current session, before launch kafka, just execute manually the export command to overwrite JAVA_HOME to point 1.8

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I've been a little busy lately so I haven't had the chance to continue with this issue. But I will update you as soon as I get the opportunity.